# How to get Layout width modified in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm struggling in using a RecyclerView with a layout that has some listeners.

The code is this

- ViewHolder

  ```
   public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

      public TextView tickerSymbol;
      public TextView companyName;
      public View highlightBuy;
      public LinearLayout categoryImage;
      public LayoutParams categoryLayoutParams;
      public LinearLayout arrowImage;
      public ImageView categoryIconSeparator;
      public ImageView arrowSeparator;
      public ImageView arrowIcon;
      public RelativeLayout stockRow;
      public LinearLayout tickerInfo;
      public Boolean isCategoryOpened = false;

      public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
          super(itemView);
          this.tickerSymbol = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_symbol_textview);
          this.companyName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.company_name_textview);
          this.highlightBuy = itemView.findViewById(R.id.highlight_buy_view);
          this.categoryImage = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_image);
          this.categoryLayoutParams = (LayoutParams) categoryImage.getLayoutParams();
          this.arrowImage = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow);
          this.categoryIconSeparator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.category_icon_separator);
          this.arrowSeparator = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_separator);
          this.arrowIcon = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_icon_imageview);
          this.stockRow = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.stock_row);
          this.tickerInfo = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_info);
      }
  }
  ```
- onCreateViewHolder

  ```
  @Override
  public StockListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    Context context = parent.getContext();
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    View stockView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stock_list_row, parent, false);

    return new StockListAdapter.ViewHolder(stockView);
  }
  ```
- onBindViewHolder

  ```
  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(final StockListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Stock stock = mStocks.get(position);
    final int collapsedCategoryWidth = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.collapsed_category_icon_width);
    final int stockRowHeight = (int) mContext.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.stock_row_height);

    //Reset holder status
    if (holder.isCategoryOpened) {
        holder.isCategoryOpened = false;
        holder.categoryImage.getLayoutParams().width = collapsedCategoryWidth;
        holder.categoryImage.setLayoutParams(holder.categoryImage.getLayoutParams());
        holder.arrowIcon.setRotationY(0);
    }

    holder.tickerSymbol.setText(stock.ticker);

    holder.companyName.setText(stock.name);
    holder.companyName.setSelected(true);
    holder.companyName.requestFocus();

    holder.categoryImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          final int newWidth;
          final int startWidth;
          final int startArrowAngle;
          final int newArrowAngle;

          if (!holder.isCategoryOpened) {
              holder.isCategoryOpened = true;
              newWidth = holder.stockRow.getWidth() - holder.categoryLayoutParams.leftMargin - holder.arrowImage.getWidth() - ((LayoutParams) holder.arrowImage.getLayoutParams()).rightMargin - holder.categoryIconSeparator.getWidth();
              startWidth = collapsedCategoryWidth;
              startArrowAngle = 0;
              newArrowAngle = 180;
          } else {
              holder.isCategoryOpened = false;
              newWidth = collapsedCategoryWidth;
              startWidth = holder.categoryImage.getWidth();
              startArrowAngle = 180;
              newArrowAngle = 0;
          }

          Animation a = new Animation() {
              @Override
              protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                  holder.categoryLayoutParams.width = startWidth + (int) ((newWidth - startWidth) * interpolatedTime);
                  //MAYBE PROBLEM HERE??
                  holder.categoryImage.setLayoutParams(holder.categoryLayoutParams);
                  holder.arrowIcon.setRotationY(startArrowAngle + (newArrowAngle - startArrowAngle) * interpolatedTime);
              }
          };
          a.setDuration(500);
          holder.categoryImage.startAnimation(a);
      }
  });
  ```

I'll attach a sample of the bug I have.

[image: Bug Part One]

When I first click a view, the onClick work successfully, but if I scroll and then go back to that view, only the arrow gets flipped (which means the onClick gets called) but the LinearLayout Width won't get modified.

But now what's really strange is that if I click on another view that hasn't been clicked before, or (I guess) hasn't been recycled, happens the following:

[image: Bug Part Two]

So I guess, the Width is set, but isn't show.

I don't really know how to fix this.

An help or other ideas are appreciated!

Here is what I've already tried:

- Putting the status in the stock;
- Putting the listener outside the adapter;
- Putting the listener inside the holder;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved, the thing that was causing all this misfunctions was the `holder.companyName.requestFocus()` that I was calling to get the marquee working in the TextView.

It comes out I don't need the `requestFocus()` to get it working, and that it was the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

add 1 variable in your store class to stored value if you already clicked on that item or not..

the ilustration like this , i set variable isSelected in store :

```
 private boolean mSelected=false;

 public boolean getIsSelected(){
        return this.mSelected;
    }
    public void setIsSelected(boolean mSelected){
        this.mSelected=mSelected;
    }
```

and then in your onClick method just add `stock.setIsSelected(!stock.getIsSelected())` after if conditional and set your if conditional to read boolean from `stock.getIsSelected()` and the last, just remove variable isCategoryOpened from your holder.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        final int newWidth;
        final int startWidth;
        final int startArrowAngle;
        final int newArrowAngle;

        if (stock.getIsSelected()) {
            newWidth = holder.stockRow.getWidth() - holder.categoryLayoutParams.leftMargin - holder.arrowImage.getWidth() - ((LayoutParams) holder.arrowImage.getLayoutParams()).rightMargin - holder.categoryIconSeparator.getWidth();
            startWidth = collapsedCategoryWidth;
            startArrowAngle = 0;
            newArrowAngle = 180;
        } else {
            newWidth = collapsedCategoryWidth;
            startWidth = holder.categoryImage.getWidth();
            startArrowAngle = 180;
            newArrowAngle = 0;
        }
       stock.setIsSelected(!stock.getIsSelected())
        Animation a = new Animation() {
            @Override
            protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
                holder.categoryLayoutParams.width = startWidth + (int) ((newWidth - startWidth) * interpolatedTime);
                //MAYBE PROBLEM HERE??
                holder.categoryImage.setLayoutParams(holder.categoryLayoutParams);
                holder.arrowIcon.setRotationY(startArrowAngle + (newArrowAngle - startArrowAngle) * interpolatedTime);
            }
        };
        a.setDuration(500);
        holder.categoryImage.startAnimation(a);
    }
```

Correct me if i'm wrong :)

Comment: Why passing the position to the stock? I shoud use it in the List... The stock object is fetched from my data using that position

Comment: +1. This is the way I probably would choose. Saving the internal state of an item is the easiest (and cleanest) solution for this case.
The RecyclerView will take the items that are not visible anymore (after scrolling for example) and "recycles" them for new items. The common case for that is scrolling up and down because some items disappear at the one end and some others become visible at the other end.

Comment: I've tried it, but is still the same :( I guess is an Android bug bound to the width setting

Comment: I've tried, but it gets worse, now the view is cloned and not restored